# Saving Base64 Inline Image to Database

Tags: java, javascript, base64

I am allowing a user to upload a photo via javascript and a file uploader to a web page. Basically it just copies the base64 string to an image tag's src.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event){
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
            core.DOM.on(img, 'mouseover mouseout', function() {
                core.DOM.toggleClass(this, 'over');
            });
            core.DOM.on(img, 'click', function(e) {
                core.DOM.addClass(this, 'focus');
                if(this.nextSibling != toolsContainer) {
                    referenceNode = this;
                    container.insertBefore(toolsContainer, referenceNode.nextSibling);
                }
            });
            //Append new element.
            if(referenceNode != toolsContainer) {
                container.insertBefore(img, referenceNode.nextSibling);
            } else {
                container.insertBefore(img, referenceNode);
            }
            clearFileInput(imageLoader); //Prepare file input for another upload.
        }
        img.src = event.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
```

I then pass the html to the server through ajax:

```
var content = imageContainer.innerHTML;
core.post('blog/upload', 'p=' + JSON.stringify({'content': content, 'title': title}),      function(req) {
    console.log(req);
});
```

Server side I am simply saving the html to a database:

```
JSONObject json = JSONObject.fromObject(request.getParameter("p"));
String title = json.getString("title");
byte[] content = ((String) json.get("content")).getBytes();
Blog.post(user, title, content);
```

Server side I take the image tag (which includes the base64 string), convert it to a byte array so it can be stored in mysql via a MEDIUMBLOB. When I retrieve it, I simply convert the byte[] back to a string and post the string on the browser. I was assuming the image tag and its content would just show up normally. It appears to look normal but apparently something is getting corrupted or damaged in the process.

When I retrieve the image tag from the database and display it in the browser, the image is corrupted. Am I missing a step here? Can I not just pass a string of base64 binary data to the server and save it?

Comment: assuming the image is base64 encoded, you should be _explicitly_ using the "US-ASCII" charset when converting between bytes and chars.

Comment: Are you talking about the portion of java code that converts to byte[]? Or should this be done in the javascript before posting to the server?

Comment: as far as i can tell, javascript is treating the content like string data.  i only see java code which converts a string(chars) to byte[].  again, that's assuming the image content is base64 in the client.